# Why doesn’t “sound” end in “s” in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Here’s the sentence:

> Did you ever hear anyone sound so peculiar?

Is it the same rule as in these sentences?

> I made him **do** it.
>
> I’ll have her **go** to take it back.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't end with '**s**' because it's the (bare) **infinitive**, which is used without '**to**' after verbs like **hear**, bid, let, make, see, need, dare, etc.

https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/

Answer (score -2):

Sound in this sentence is a noun, so you are talking about the 'sound' of his/her voice, not the 'sounds' that he/she is making.

'Do' and 'go' are both verbs, so they do not follow the same rule.

Comment: If it’s in affirmative form, it would be: “You have heard someone sound so peculiar.” I don’t agree with your saying that “sound” here is a noun.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `sound` here is a verb